# Room invalidation tracker is initialized twice in 1.1.1

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-9.0-pie

Did someone experienced this issue with Room 1.1.1, too? I've read in a similar thread here and on Github that there was a bug with 1.1.0 and this should be fixed in 1.1.1. The error turns up on Android 9 devices and doesen't effect the app (until now). The following code is the StackTrace that has no error in my code but in the Room Framework

```
E/ROOM: Cannot run invalidation tracker. Is the db closed?
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The database '' is not open.
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.throwIfNotOpenLocked(SQLiteDatabase.java:2287)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.createSession(SQLiteDatabase.java:409)
    at android.database.sqlite.-$$Lambda$RBWjWVyGrOTsQrLCYzJ_G8Uk25Q.get(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal$SuppliedThreadLocal.initialValue(ThreadLocal.java:284)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:180)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:170)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.getThreadSession(SQLiteDatabase.java:403)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.getSession(SQLiteProgram.java:101)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
    at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(FrameworkSQLiteStatement.java:45)
    at android.arch.persistence.room.InvalidationTracker$1.run(InvalidationTracker.java:321)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Did someone experience this, too? Is there a fix? Updating to androidx is currently not an option.

Comment: Similar issue here. This is with `androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha04`. Did you remove the database path on purpose on the second line of your log?

Comment: Is there any instance where you call `db.close()` on your code? try commenting it out and post the log results if applicable

Comment: it works for me now, do you know why? how do I close the db properly without crashing?